# React Multiselect checkbox filtering data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, codesandbox

I have an [application](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-kmb4d?file=/src/App.js) retrieving a list of todos from this [endpoint](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/)

I have built a `CheckBoxDropDown` component to select the id of each `todo`

In the `CheckBoxDropDown.js` component i am passing as prop the function `onChange`

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSelected(value);
    onChange(value);
};

<Select
    labelId="mutiple-select-label"
    multiple
    value={selected}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
    MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
```

In `App.js` i am passing the data ( tasks ) to my component, everything works fine.

```
<CheckBoxDropDown onChange={handleFilterTasks} tasks={tasks} />
```

How can i filter in my `handleFilterTasks` method the task or tasks id for any id i select in the dropdown ?

This is what i am trying to do but i can not get my result array with the filter data por id selected

```
  const handleFilterTasks = (item, e) => {
    const task = e
    const userId = tasks[e]
    const result = tasks.filter(val => val.id !== userId);
    console.log(result);
    // setFilteredData(task);
  }
```

You can see the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68247206-forked-kmb4d?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with filtering your values array. You have the array which renders the list and you have the selected value.
Consider below example. This will return an array with selected UserId (here, 4). After the array is filtered, you can call setSelected(filteredArray) to update the table.
Let me know if this works! Please mark it as answer if it works!

```
const valuesList = [{id: 1, name:'spray'}, {id:2, name:'limit'}, {id:3, name:'elite'}, {id:4, name:'exuberant'}];
const userId = 4

const result = valuesList.filter(val => val.id == userId);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I accept as answer the code related to the codesandbox that i link in the question, thanks.